# How to set custom thumbnail for video upload with dailymotion api

Tags: c#, dailymotion-api

How to set custom thumbnail for video upload with Dailymotion API. I'm using this https://github.com/cbenard/SODailyMotionUpload/tree/master/SO%20Dailymotion%20Upload and it works for everything else just can't able to find a way to add a custom thumbnail. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the field "thumbnail_url".

For exemple in php :

```
    $result = $api->call('video.create', 
                     array(
                         'url' => $url, 
                         'title' => 'My awesome video', 
                         'channel' => 'fun',
                         'thumbnail_url' => 'http://www.website.com/thumb.png',
                         'description' => 'My awesome description', 
                         'tags' => 'test,tags', 
                         'published' => true
                     ));
```